# How does Half Life's covering work?

Tags: algorithm, ai, path-finding, valve

Enemies in this game take cover. AFAIK HL uses some logical decisions for enemy to start searching for cover and to abandon cover, and I am able so far to find them; but how does he find a cover place?

I know HL has waypoints. I can only guess/speculate how they find cover point. They might search for nearest waypoint which has certain properties; I thought such node might have some "cover" tag but tutorials seem not to mention it; so maybe it is a node which is not visible by player AND offers attack possibility (crate or edge of wall).

Thank You. :)

Comment: You could always take a look at the [Half-Life source code](http://www.fileplanet.com/81538/80000/fileinfo/Full-Half-Life-SDK-2.3-%28source-only%29 "Half-Life source code").

Comment: Are you asking about Half-life or Half-life 2? Your question doesn't make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the AI is actually misleading. The AI in Half-Life is very scripted, even though it doesn't appear to be so, which is why they can appear to exhibit intelligent behaviours.

Comment: "Very scripted" meaning what?

Comment: Yes, it is scripted. But difference btw scripted and non-scipted is that one is former is not direct. So I do not understand what You mean.

Comment: On the other had You can mean, that every cover is precomputed and they just select from it. But I do not think they would insert cover places directly into code ...

Comment: Do you mean "scripted" as in: instead of code hardcoded into the main game files, they have have a lot of python (or otherwise) scripts read into the engine? Or did a human put together a script of what they should do when like a movie script (when Freeman is in X do C, D or E, when Freeman is in Y do A, B or C)? Do you mean "very" as in "the amount of scripts are great" or "there is oustanding depth and intricacy to these scripts"? Or do you mean something else entirely to all of these things. Hopefully I am conveying just how nondescript the words "very scripted" are.